# JQuery if element contains string then execute class swap issues

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get this little script in JQUERY to work but I'm having issues.  Anybody see what I'm doing wrong?  The purpose is to look at this line:

```
<a id="dnn_dnnLogin_enhancedLoginLink" title="Logout" class="LoginLink" href="/Home/tabid/357/ctl/Logoff/Default.aspx">Logout</a>
```

If it has the string 'logout' then it should swap the class of another div .navDiv to .navDivLoggedIn

```
  var elem = $('dnn_dnnLogin_enhancedLoginLink');
    if (elem.contains('Logout')) {
       var navelem = $('.navDiv');
       $(navelem).attr('class','navDivLoggedIn');
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For starters, `$('dnn_dnnLogin_enhancedLoginLink');` doesn't refer to anything. It should be `$('#dnn_dnnLogin_enhancedLoginLink');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`contains` isn't a jQuery function**, it is more a regex type within the selector itself.

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

You meant to do:

```
if ( $('#dnn_dnnLogin_enhancedLoginLink:contains("Logout")') ) {
    // stuff
}
```

You could of also done a simple `.indexOf()` on the text/html of your element to test if Logout is inside the element.

```
// you were also missing the # for ID
var elem = $('#dnn_dnnLogin_enhancedLoginLink');

if (elem.text().indexOf('Logout') > -1) {
    // stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `#` in the prefix for the **ID** attribute:

```
var elem = $('#dnn_dnnLogin_enhancedLoginLink');
          ____^____
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors. As I noted in the comments, you aren't using the proper syntax to select an element via its ID. Second, there's no need to create variables for everything when you can just use the jQuery selectors on the element immediately. Finally, you're using the wrong contains function.

Try:

```
if ($('#dnn_dnnLogin_enhancedLoginLink:contains("Logout")').length) {
    $('.navDiv').addClass('navDivLoggedIn');
};
```

Here's a simplified **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/buz6s/)** that should do what you need.

Comment: +1 for noticing the `.contains` error too - this will fix his problem

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work using toggleClass and :contains, and id indicator `"#"`. jQuery elements don't have .contains() as method you must use it like this

```
var elem = $('#dnn_dnnLogin_enhancedLoginLink:contains("Logout")');
if (elem.length > 0) {
    var navelem = $('.navDiv');
    navelem.toggleClass('navDiv navDivLoggedIn');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 $('dnn_dnnLogin_enhancedLoginLink');
```

By

```
 $('#dnn_dnnLogin_enhancedLoginLink');
```

You should use same selectors in jquery like in CSS, so as you id of you element is "dnn_dnnLogin_enhancedLoginLink", you should use "#dnn_dnnLogin_enhancedLoginLink"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 if( $("a.LoginLink").text().str.indexOf("Logout") >= 0)
 {
   var navelem = $('.navDiv');
   $(navelem).attr('class','navDivLoggedIn');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dnn_dnnLogin_enhancedLoginLink').text().contains('Logout')
```

Apart from the missing `#` from your selector, You cannot do `contains()` on the selector directly. Use `.text()` or `.html()` to get the text in the selector & then do `.contains()`